# View layers Material override - Possible in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, viewlayers

I'm looking to override materials on the same object in Eevee for different View Layers, for example a shirt color that I want multiple versions (same object and animation, but different material in each Layer Pass). This is super easy with Maya with material overrides.

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't want the material override to affect ALL View Layers, I want a different one for each View Layer, to be able to automatically render all view layers (through File Output in Compositor) without having to go and change the material manually for each pass after each render.

Thank you so much!
Carl

Answer (score 0):

There's an very cheap Addon to do this. You can also find in at Github for free, as I know.

I'm not sure if it's working per layer.

https://korchiy.gumroad.com/l/Rpswh